# buddy press ajax new message notifiction

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, buddypress

i am working on one buddy press theme and want to display unread messages count via ajax.

i have bellow code in function.php of my theme

```
<?php
function addMessageRefresh()
    {
    ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getMessages(){
    jQuery('#user-messages span').text("Unread Messages: (<?php echo messages_get_unread_count(); ?>)");
     }
   setInterval("getMessages()", 10000);
</script>
    <?php
    }
add_action( 'wp_head', 'addMessageRefresh');
?>
```

**it worked.**

but its only show unread count on page load, but if user receive any message this did’t update.

the main purpose of this script is to display total number of unread messages and it should update via ajax means if user receive any message, it should show total number of unread messages without reloading page.

Thanks

Comment: Is this ok mixing client and server script?

Comment: dear @elrado what do you mean ?

Comment: @aid did you solve it or you still need help.

Comment: still looking for help, thanks

Comment: A little  overview of the problem would be helpful. And also: is messages_get_unread_count() php function you want to call asynchronously? What do you want to do with addMessageRefresh. If you want to do it AJAX way you have to PHP write function to get messages count and then call and read it on the client. You cannot mix server and client code.

Comment: @elrado Dear thanks for your help but i am new to buddy press and did't understand your ans. can you please let me know is this possible to do so and if yes then please write a small code for me. Thanks

Comment: You need web development course :). Or somebody that will do it for you.

Comment: Jquery won't allow your <?php ?> tag inside the function ......

Answer (score 1):

somehow it..

```
function getMessages(){
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: '../url.php'
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (data) {
        jQuery('#user-messages span').text("Unread Messages: " + data);
    }}
    )
}
```

**../url.php code**

```
<?php echo messages_get_unread_count(); ?>
```

Comment: NO i am getting error, "Unread Messages: <br /> <b>Fatal error</b>: Call to undefined function messages_get_unread_count() in <b>url.php</b> on line <b>1</b><br />"

Answer (score 0):

There are several steps, that you need to do:
1) Place element which contain unread message count. This should be adde to your template.

```
<div id="unread_messages"></div>
```

2) Add javascript code which will update your count value.You can add this to your template or you can print it from wp_head/wp_footer hooks

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function update_unread_count() {
    jQuery('#unread_messages').load(
      '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>', 
      { 'action': 'get_unread_message_count' } 
    );
  }

  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    // update every 15 seconds, after page loaded
    setInterval('update_unread_count()', 15000); 
  });
</script>
```

3) Register ajax request handler. You should add this lines into your functions.php theme file

```
function my_get_unread_message_count() {
  echo messages_get_unread_count();
  die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_get_unread_message_count', 'my_get_unread_message_count');
```

Something like that.

Comment: this works, but only problem is it shows whole page in message div, is there any way to not to use admin-ajax.php, use our own function.

Comment: If you see full page content then you probably do something wrong.
First check ajax request. It should go to wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
You can use firebox extension firebug 
Also check your "action" parameter value and wp_ajax_<action_name> hook name.

Comment: Look at this article: http://w4dev.com/wp/wp_ajax/  . You can simple modify example.

Comment: i only see whole page in div, when i am logged in as non admin user. on admin login its working.

Comment: Sorry my fault. After line add_action('wp_ajax_get_unread_message_count', 'my_get_unread_message_count'); add add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_unread_message_count', 'my_get_unread_message_count');

Comment: its still same, even i add new line add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_unread_message_count', 'my_get_unread_message_count'); but if am logged in as normal user i see full page in div

Answer (score 0):

Your issue lies within:

```
jQuery('#user-messages span').text("Unread Messages: (<?php echo messages_get_unread_count(); ?>)");
```

What is being done is when the page is being loaded PHP processes the `messages_get_unread_count()` function and uses that value to render the page.  From there the generated JavaScript will be called at your interval but it will have a static value defined in your preprocessed markup.

You will need to have an AJAX call to a url that will return your message count.

This is the functionality to allow you to get the updated message count.

```
function add_message_count_js() {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
        var msg_count;
        function updateMessages() {
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
                data: {"action": "view_message_count"},
                success: function(data) {
                    jQuery('#user-messages span').text("Unread Messages: "+data);
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
        setInterval('updateMessages()', 10000);
        //]]>
    </script>
    <?php
}
add_action('wp_head', 'add_message_count_js');
```

This will add the appropriate AJAX hooks.

```
add_action('wp_ajax_view_message_count', 'view_message_count');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_view_message_count', 'view_message_count');
function view_message_count() {
    if (is_user_logged_in())
        echo messages_get_unread_count();

    die();
}
```

Both of these snippets should go in your functions.php file.

Comment: this worked in Firefox, but did't work in Chrome,internet explorere 8 in chrome it return full page Html source, i dont know whats reason, i am using wamp.

Comment: No error, but now i figure out the issue, if i am logged in as Admin then i can't see this but if i am logged in as normal user i get this problem (get html source in place of message count).

Comment: so, with that i assume that messages_get_unread_count() returns html output if the user is not logged in... try doing a test to see if the user is logged in first... i will update my post to reflect.